# Generating DifferenceRoot Equation

Tags: special-functions, difference-equations

I like to find a difference root equation I use the following methods use for mathematica but I have not get any result
Clear[p]

```
DifferenceRootReduce[(\[Pi]^(3/2)
   Gamma[3/2 + k] HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2), 1/2, 3/2 + k}, {1, 
    2 + k}, p])/(2 Gamma[2 + k]), k]

SeriesCoefficient[(\[Pi]^(3/2)
   Gamma[3/2 + k] HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2), 1/2, 3/2 + k}, {1, 
    2 + k}, p])/(2 Gamma[2 + k]), {p, 0, k}, Method -> "Holonomic"]
```

it is possible that Mathematica do not interpret the hypergeometric function cause maple does the difference equations
thanks anyway

Comment: Have you already seen [this](https://risc.jku.at/sw/holonomicfunctions/)?

Comment: not but I try thanks